# pydc1394 not recognizing Point Grey Flea3 Camera

Tags: python, camera, libdc1394

I am running Python 2.7 on Mac OS X. I have downloaded and installed pydc1394 so as to have it as a python library. I'm trying to run the save_image.py program. The camera is connected via USB to my Mac. When I try to run the code, however, I get an error saying

```
Opening camera!
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 100, in <module>
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/pydc1394/camera2.py", line 1009, in __init__
IndexError: list index out of range
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

The code for pydc1394 can be found in https://github.com/jordens/pydc1394.

My guess is that it doesn't sense the camera, however I am sure that it is 1394 compatible, and that it is connected to the laptop.

Thank you!

Comment: 1394 as in FireWire, but you are connecting the camera to a USB port?

Comment: So as far as I know what the pydc1394 library does is wrap the libdc1394 which is used to interface with the camera that I have. I am not quite sure if it requires a FireWire connection. I will try this out tomorrow and update the post. Aside from that are there any other things I am missing that may not let the camera be detected by the library?